# Tag/Button design is inconsistent

Tags: bug, design

I understand that the new design is intended towards flat design. Tag buttons in some places such as the question section have been flat:

[image]

But tags in some places (non-button ones, it seems) have shaded border, making it look 3D:

[image]

And there are some buttons, like the "Save Edit" button, that look more 3D:

[image]

These are inconsistent. If the intended design philosophy is flat design, then the latter two examples that I showed should become flat.

Comment: The second image is from an ad. Those buttons aren't part of the page. That probably won't be changed until they update the ads for Careers.

Comment: I personally do like the little 3D effect on the buttons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tags in the Ads are served from elsewhere, not part of the new SO css. But we'll be fixing that soon. As far as the "flat design philosophy" goes, I don't want to be dogmatic about it. The 3d effect is reserved for buttons to give affordance.

Comment: "An `affordance` is often taken as a relation between an object or an environment and an organism, that affords the opportunity for that organism to perform an action. For example, a knob affords twisting, and perhaps pushing, while a cord affords pulling. As a relation, an affordance exhibits the possibility of some action, and is not a property of either an organism or its environment alone."